# How can I check if a variable from a function parameter matches a variable outside the function in c++?

Tags: c++, function, logic

For example, if in the beginning of my main() function I have the user cin a value for an int x and then I have a function like same(int y) that uses a variable y which is read in from a file, how could I check (inside the same() function) that the parameter int y is the same as the int x?

Comment: Please show some example code that fills in the parts you currently have or that need to be a certain way. You can add comments in the code where you're unsure of how to proceed. It's not clear from your description what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Normally if you want a function to perform an operation on two variables (such as comparing them in your case) you pass both of them to the function such as `bool same(int x, int y);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
class CompareXY {
  private:
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

  public:
    void EnterX {
      cout << "Enter the x value: ";
      cin >> x;
    }

    void EnterY {
      //idk which way you used to get the 'y' but it goes here (and you store it in the 'int y' previously created in the private section)

    }

    void compare {
      if (x == y) {
        //whatever should happen
      }
    }
};

int main() {
  CompareXY c;
  c.EnterX();
  c.EnterY();
  c.compare();
  return 0;
}
```

I think this should work, but if it doesn't at least I hope it helps you.